# Using SED with no options? sed 's#.*/##'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I've got a command that I am trying to understand. Main issue is that the SED command doesn't line up with any examples I've seen before. I don't understand why

```
find . -name *_<templateName>_*|sed 's#.*/##' > wc_uDriveFiles<monYYYY>.txt
```

Comment: Examples usually use / as the delimiter but you can use ANY character.  In your example the delimiter is #.  So your sed command replaces stuff followed by a slash with nothing (effectively deleting it)

Comment: @Jerry that makes sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: Note that the first non-option argument is treated as a script text if, and only if, no other script is passed (by -e (script text) or -f (script file)). The man page is pretty good these days.

Comment: Note: If you want to match a line that contains a `/` you can either use `sed '/\//' file` or `sed '\#/#' file`. The second example changes the regexp delimiter to `#`  i.e. to change the delimiter for a regexp address, precede that character with `\ ` e.g. `sed '\@/@' file` will also match a `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed's `s` command performs search-and-substitute.
The following letter (here `#`) separates *pattern*, *replacement* and *options*.
Note that regex pattern is taken greedy.

An example should clarify how it works

```
$ cat file.txt
abc
ab/c
a/b/c

$ sed 's#.*/##' file.txt
abc
c
c
```

So, text up to and including the last slash, if any, gets dropped